# Вывод chunk'ов

Tags: modx, cms, шаблоны

Дано: шаблон, у которого желательно не создавать дубликат.

Необходимо: Вывести `chunk` для определённых страниц внутри `head` шаблона.

Подскажите, как это можно реализовать в `ModX`? Может есть что-то наподобие `"if"` для `chunk`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если вы хотите выводить чанк для определенной страницы, допустим с `Id = 11`, то нужно создать сниппет с содержимым:

```
$id = 11;
$id_tek = $modx->documentIdentifier; //узнаем текущий id страницы
if ($id_tek == $id){
     $modx->getChunk('chunkName');   //выводим чанк с именем chunkName
}
```

и потом вставить этот сниппет в `HEAD` вашего шаблона.
PS. Рассмотрен пример для `MODx Evo`